# How to add "or" statement in ISession.QueryOver?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, nhibernate, isession

I have a question:

Is there a way to add "or" statement in ISession.QueryOver ?

Consider I have these values:

```
val1 = 0;
val2=0;
```

and my query:

```
.Where(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property()=>obj1.val1),val1) //Or statement should comes to here
.Where(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property()=>obj1.val2),val2)
```

So I need to get the datas whose val1 equals to local val1 OR whose val2 equals to val2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    .Add(Restrictions.Or(
        Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property()=>obj1.val1),val1), 
        Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property()=>obj1.val2),val2)
             )
        )
```